# Django 1.4 Deployment and os.environ.setdefault

Tags: django, deployment, django-1.4

In the new Django 1.4 project layout, I have a declaration of os.environ.setdefault on manage.py and wsgi.py inside the project folder. What is the difference between the two?

Also, if I have this settings structure:

```
mysite
|-- mysite
|   |-- settings
|   |-- base.py
|   |-- dev.py
|   |-- production.py
|   wsgi.py
|-- myapp
|-- manage.py
```

which os.environ.setdefault should I edit? The one in manage.py or the one in wsgi.py?

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

also, in which file should I detect the current env? and how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So manage.py is never executed once deployed, its mainly for development and/or executing commands against your project so its the wsgi.py that you're interested in.

You can check this by looking at the file itself which has: `if __name__ == "__main__":` that should tell you that the file is meant to be executed directly from command line.